# URL generated on running one line deploy script on EC2 Ubuntu VM is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rasa, rasa-x

I ran [one line deploy script](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/install/quick-install-script) on an AWS EC2 instance which in turn spins up a k3s (lightweight kubernetes) cluster and returns a URL to access my [Rasa bot](https://rasa.com/) (open source chatbot development platform).

[image: Generated URL]
When I tried running the URL in the browser, it doesn’t respond. (couldn’t connect)

I figured that that might be happening because of port 80 (HTTP port on AWS) not being open. I checked and access to port 80 is allowed but the URL still doesn't seem to work. Kindly help me figure out a solution to the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see because you didn't fully blot out the IP address that it starts with `172`. The URL is using the private IP of the EC2 instance. You need to modify the URL to use the public IP of the EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. How do you suggest I do that since the URL is generated automatically on running the deployment script (curl -s get-rasa-x.rasa.com | sudo bash)?

Comment: If you just need the URL to paste into your browser, then go get the public IP from the AWS console and change the URL manually.

Comment: The URL is working fine now. Didn't need to modify it. The problem was with port 80 (it was closed).